# Thread was being aborted. For response.redirect. how to redirect when session is Null in following code

Tags: c#, webforms

how to redirect when session is Null in following code .   Thread was being aborted is the exception i am facing

```
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["mail"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException r)
        {

            Response.End();
        }

        await Task.Run(() => retrivelast());
  }
```

Comment: Why not just check if the session is null and if so redirect?

Comment: protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
          if (Session["mail"] == null)
           {
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
                    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            }           
            await Task.Run(() => retrivelast());
   }



This way?? if so same error

Comment: That's not checking for if `Session` is null. It may be that I've misunderstood what you want but if you actually want to check if the Session is null then you need to do `if (Session==null)`. It may be that you actually mean "How to redirect when `Session["mail"]` is null" though in which case my comment is not so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `Response.Redirect` portion of code to somewhere outside of the Try..Catch block.

The way Response.Redirect works in ASP.net is that is purposefully throws an exception to completely halt the further processing of the web page. This helps ensure that your redirect works properly, and that further processing actions do not cause conflicting behavior.

Here is another SO post with more information, and alternative solutions:
[Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

### Edit

I didn't notice the **async** on the Page_Load method at first. That would explain why you are still seeing the error. Please see these SO questions:

[ASP.NET 4.5 async-await and Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125361/asp-net-4-5-async-await-and-response-redirect)

[Response.Redirect issue with Asp.net async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147825/response-redirect-issue-with-asp-net-async)

Comment: I removed it from try catch block and still same error

Comment: I think you meant to write "Remove `Reponse.Redirect` from *inside* the try..catch".

Comment: Chris Thanks! @vibhav patil Can you post your updated code that still has the issue? Also, be aware that while debugging, you will see the error get thrown, and if you have VS settings to "Break on Exceptions", then your code will pause at that line showing the error, however it should continue running after, without killing the process.

Comment: @ryancdotnet

protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
          if (Session["mail"] == null)
           {
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
                    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
                       
            await Task.Run(() => retrivelast());
   }

Comment: @vibhavpatil I believe the issue is async. I've updated my answer with some SO reference. I hope they help!

Comment: @ryancdotnet can you please help me with it? getting confused .

protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
         if (Session["mail"] == null) 
         { 
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 
         } 
await Task.Run(() => retrivelast());
 }

Comment: @ryancdotnet thaks it worked. mistake was from my side. 
I had to add this line in my logout button. 
Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);
Sorry